# Why is not WebGL Drawing?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have this very simple (yet big) code that doesn't work. The triangle doesn't show.
It just pass 3 vertexes already multiplied by a ortho-matrix. Do nothing in vertex shader, and paint white in fragment shader.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var gl;
        _main_web = function() {
            gl = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("experimental-webgl");
            gl.clearColor(1,0,0,1);
            gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
            gl.viewport(0, 0, 640, 480);
            gl.clearDepth(1);

            buffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,buffer);
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
new Float32Array([[-1, -1, -0.12000000476837158, 1, 
0, 1, -0.12000000476837158, 1, 
1, -1, -0.12000000476837158, 1]]),
            gl.STATIC_DRAW);

            vert_shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
            gl.shaderSource(vert_shader,"attribute vec4 vertex;void main(void) {gl_Position = vertex;}\n");
            gl.compileShader(vert_shader);
            if( !gl.getShaderParameter(vert_shader,gl.COMPILE_STATUS ) ) {
                throw 0;
            }

            frag_shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
            gl.shaderSource(frag_shader,"void main(void) { gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0); } \n");
            gl.compileShader(frag_shader);
            if( !gl.getShaderParameter(frag_shader,gl.COMPILE_STATUS) ) {
                throw 1;
            }

            program = gl.createProgram();
            gl.attachShader(program,vert_shader);
            gl.attachShader(program,frag_shader);
            gl.linkProgram(program);
            if( !gl.getProgramParameter(program,gl.LINK_STATUS) ) {
                throw 2;
            }

            vertexLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program,"vertex");

            gl.deleteShader(frag_shader);
            gl.deleteShader(vert_shader);
            gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

            gl.useProgram(program);
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,buffer);
            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vertexLocation);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexLocation,4,gl.FLOAT,false,0,0);

            gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES,0,3);
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        body {
            margin:0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="_main_web()">
    <canvas id="canvas" width=640 height=480>

    </canvas>
</body>
```

I am debugging the whole afternoon and couldn't find the error. getError always return 0. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gl.drawArrays(4,3,0);
```

This looks weird. Should look like:

```
gl.drawArrays(
    /* mode */ gl.TRIANGLES,
    /* first vertex */ 0,
    /* num vertices */ 3
);
```

---

Also (unimportant):

```
gl.useProgram(program);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,buffer);
```

The last `bindBuffer` isn't important at this moment. You need it when you set an attribute location with `gl.vertexAttribPointer`, but once it's set you can change the `ARRAY_BUFFER` binding to anything.

You would need to do this if several attributes were located in different VBOs.

(Note: This is not the case for `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` bindings, which must be set if you do `drawElements` or something.)

Comment: Hi, 4 is gl.TRIANGLES (I traced my original software to obtain the OpenGL calls and forgot to replace 4 with gl.TRIANGLES). I see I've switched drawArrays arguments first-vertex and num-vertices. I've just fixed it but it stills doesn' t work, I've edited the main question with the code changes. Is there anything else wrong?

Comment: I got it, double [[ on buffer data definition!

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it by 5 minutes :) Shows what I get for being wordy.

Answer (score 3):

With your modified code, I was able to get it to render the white triangle by removing the extra set of [] around the Float32Array constructor call. So go from this:

```
new Float32Array([[-1, -1, -0.12000000476837158, 1, 
0, 1, -0.12000000476837158, 1, 
1, -1, -0.12000000476837158, 1]]),
```

to this

```
new Float32Array([-1, -1, -0.12000000476837158, 1, 
0, 1, -0.12000000476837158, 1, 
1, -1, -0.12000000476837158, 1]),
```

I imagine that it was a simple typo, but for the sake or clarity: `new Float32Array()` expects to be given an array of numbers, which it will then "cast" to 32 bit floating point values. You were passing it an array that contained a single item, which was also an array. It doesn't know how to handle that so the cast fails, and as such you were being returned a Float32Array that contained 1 value: NaN.

Comment: Uh... Didn't Javascript have exceptions or something to indicate such cases non-silently? :-) Nice catch

Comment: Invalid Javascript !== Nonsensical Javascript. This statement is "valid" in purely syntactical terms, and the function itself is written to simply treat any value that's not trivially convertible to a float as NaN, so it executes just fine. Were Javascript strongly typed, this is the type of error we could catch, but it's not so we can't. Reality of the language. (Of course, if JS was strongly typed we wouldn't need this function in the first place. Go figure!)

Comment: But exceptions were invented to avoid (among others) this exact kind of problem, and hey, this function still uses a magic value to report precondition failure! Uncool.

Comment: No, exceptions were not invented to avoid this kind of problem. JavaScript defines how things get converted. Those conversions were applied. See section 9 of http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf